# In TypeScript, is there any method to type function return values to the function itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, functional-programming

For the last week, I've been researching how it could be possible to type function return values to the funtion itself in TypeScript.

What is hard to me is types are not the first-class object in TypeScript(or any other type systems, not sure).

In a sense, I'm seeking a way for Self-reference types; not only identifies itself but also distinguishes from any others.

In fact, I've implemented such a thing in vanilaJS.

#### example1: `Member` type to a return value of a function: `Member`

```
log("=Are you a member? ========= ");
const Member = a => Type(Member)([a]); // Member = a=>[a]

const alice = ["Alice"];
const bob = Member("Bob"); //["Bob"]

log(
    isType(Member)(alice)
);//false
log(
    isType(Member)(bob)
);//true
```

#### example2: `specialOperation` type to a certain functions

```
log("=Is this a special operation? ========= ");
const specialOperation = f => Type(specialOperation)(f);

const f1 = a => a + 1; //vanilla function
const f2 = Type(specialOperation) //typed function
    (a => {
        //This function might be considered to be "special" 
        //because it does some featured operations in a context.
        return a * 2;
    });

log(
    isType(specialOperation)(f1)
);//false
log(
    isType(specialOperation)(f2)
);//true
log(
    f2(1) // f2 = a => a * 2
);//2  // just in case, let you know
```

#### exapmples and test

```js
//--- debug use
const log = (m) => {
    console.log(m); //IO
    return m;
};
//---- a type sysetm in vanillaJS 
const typedPrimitive = T => i => {
    const derived = Object(i);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(derived, Object(i));
    const typeProperty = {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: true
    };
    Object.defineProperty(derived, T, typeProperty);
    return derived;
};

const typedObject = T => i => {
    const handler = {
        get: (target, name) => name == T//must ==
            ? true : target[name]
    };
    return new Proxy(i, handler);
};

const typed = T => i => (i !== Object(i))//primitives
    ? typedPrimitive(T)(i)
    : typedObject(T)(i)

const istype = T => i => i[T] === true;

const Type = T => i => (i === T) || (i == null)
    ? i
    : typed(T)(i);

const isType = T => i => (i === T)
    ? true
    : (i == null)
        ? false
        : istype(T)(i);
//------------------------------------------


log("=Are you a member? ========= ");
const Member = a => Type(Member)([a]); // M = a=>[a]

const alice = ["Alice"];
const bob = Member("Bob"); //["Bob"]

log(
    isType(Member)(alice)
);//false
log(
    isType(Member)(bob)
);//true

log("=Is this a special operation? ========= ");
const specialOperation = f => Type(specialOperation)(f);

const f1 = a => a + 1; //vanilla function
const f2 = Type(specialOperation) //typed function
    (a => {
        //This function might be considered to be "special" 
        //because it does some featured operations in a context.
        return a * 2;
    });

log(
    isType(specialOperation)(f1)
);//false
log(
    isType(specialOperation)(f2)
);//true
log(
    f2(1) // f2 = a => a * 2
);//2  // just in case, let you know

log("=type test of nontyped=========================");
const I = a => a;  //just a dummy function

log(
    isType(I)(I) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(1) // false
);
log(
    isType(I)([]) // fakse
);
log(
    isType(I)({}) // false
);
log(
    isType(I)("hello") //fakse
);
log(
    isType(I)(x => x) // false
);
log(
    isType(I)(true) // false
);
log(
    isType(I)(false) // false
);

log("=type test of typed=========================");

log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(I)) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(1)) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)([])) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)({})) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)("hello")) //true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(x => x)) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(true)) // true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(false)) // true
);
log(
    (Type(I)(false) == false)
        ? "Type(I)(false) == false  (as should be)"
        : "something is wrong"
);
log(
    (Type(I)(false) !== false)//Object !== Primitive
        ? "Type(I)(false) !== false  (as should be)"
        : "something is wrong"
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(NaN)) //true
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(undefined)) // false
);
log(
    isType(I)(Type(I)(null)) // false
);
log(
    Type(I)(1) + Type(I)(2)//3
);
log(
    Type(I)([1, 2, 3])
);//[1, 2, 3]
```

Although I think this method is quite useful in JavaScript, and the code runs also in TypeScript, I wonder if it's possible to implement in a sophisticated TypeScript way, because if there is better and "native manner" to do this in TypeScript, mixing another implementation by my own should be quite redundant.

Thank you.

Comment: Typescript types only exist at compile time. Are you asking how to use the return type of a function in a type guard checked by the compiler, or how to discover the return type of a function at runtime?

Comment: Thanks. As you mention, TypeScript is for static, surely, asking in that sense.   ,  how to use the return type of a function in a type guard checked by the compiler

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) introduced in typescript 2.8:

```
let someFunction: () => String;
let x : ReturnType<typeof someFunction>;
```

In case you are curious about the design alternatives the typescript team considered, the discussion in [#6606](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) provides a good overview.

Comment: Thank you, Probably, it's clear to you, but it would be much more helpful if you kindly add some basic usage of your code.