# TypeScript combining *.js + *.d.ts again?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

TypeScript `tsc -d` "declaration" of "compilerOptions" generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.

For instance, from:

#### tmp.ts

```
const log = (m: unknown) => {
    console.log((m)); 
    return m;
};
```

it generates:

#### tmp.js

```
const log = (m) => {
    console.log((m));
    return m;
};
```

and:

#### tmp.d.ts

```
declare const log: (m: unknown) => unknown;
```

I think this is quite interesting because it "devides" the TypeScript source code to a native JavaScript code and the extra type definition.

Then, here is my thought. After deviding the native code and type definition, is it easily possilbe to generate a valid TypeScript code by re-binding both codes.

For instance:

#### tmp-reunion.ts

```
declare const log1: (m: unknown) => unknown;

const log1 = m => {
    console.log((m)); 
    return m;
};
```

This code generates an errors:

```
[ts] Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'log1'.
```

for each statements.

Why am I doing this?

I'm motivated by facts:

1. In Algebra,

   (x^2 + 3x +2) = (x+1)(x+2) = (x^2 + 3x +2)

I want to confirm if the same thing is valid under TypeScript.

2. It's especially interesting TypeScript compiles a typed-source-code to a vanilla JavaScript code having the type information completely discarded as the output.

The fact makes me think, in a sense, the output of the vanilla JS code is type safe and valid with TypeScirpt, just without the *.d.ts file which is eventually appearently merely an extra helper functionality that TypeScript compiler takes advantage of. It's just a tool.

Accordingly, the type-safty of the vanilla JS code can be later, easily validated by TypeScript compiler with the helper functional tool, that is `tmp.d.ts`. That is what I want to confirm.

How can I make
**TypeScript combining *.js + *.d.ts again?**

Thanks.

Comment: The algebraic motivation is very vague. What is the algebraic structure here which you want to prove to be distributive? Otherwise it just sounds like "a+b = b+a, so why does order matter anywhere in the universe". Apples and oranges.

Comment: @IngoBürk It's not about commutative law, but about factorization and restoration. I thought I made it clear. I use i3, by the way.

Comment: I don't see how "factorization and restoration" in Algebra is at all relevant for this, though. There's plenty of processes in the world that aren't reversible.

Comment: @IngoBürk Yeah, I know. That's the point. In other words, is it reversible or irreversible? You certainly got the point. That's the problem. In math, the factorization is reversible, and differential is irreversible.

Comment: Alright, gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

> Accordingly, the type-safty of the vanilla JS code can be later, easily validated by TypeScript compiler with the helper functional tool, that is `tmp.d.ts`.

This is not true in general because you've lost any manual type annotations inside function bodies that were needed to validate those function bodies where TypeScript's type inference was insufficiently powerful.  For an artificial example (assuming `noImplicitAny` of course):

```
function duplicateEach<T>(arr: T[]) { 
    let out: T[] = [];
    arr.forEach(t => { out.push(t); out.push(t); });
    return out;
}
```

If you remove the annotation on `out`, the code doesn't compile because TypeScript's evolving array type inference doesn't traverse into callbacks.  If we look at the `.d.ts` and the `.js`, this annotation doesn't appear in either of them:

```
declare function duplicateEach<T>(arr: T[]): T[];

function duplicateEach(arr) {
    var out = [];
    arr.forEach(function (t) { out.push(t); out.push(t); });
    return out;
}
```

For more realistic examples, look at any nontrivial TypeScript codebase.

Comment: Thanks. In other my code, the *.d.ts is `declare const isType: (I: Function) => (i: unknown) => boolean | ((i: {
    [key: string]: object;
}) => boolean);
 ` and I thought *.d.ts doesn't lose any infromation. I don't know where to see to check the behavior the tsc -d have lost type information in *.d.ts. Can you show me where? Thanks again.

Comment: In [that particular example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575722/in-typescript-is-there-any-method-to-type-function-return-values-to-the-functio), nothing may have been lost.  I added an example in which information is lost to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I must search more complicated scenario.  I'm sorry if I miss your point, but looking at your example I feel `: T[];` in *.d.ts corresponds to `var out = [];  return out;` in the source.

Comment: Do you mean you think the compiler should infer that `var out` is of type `T[]` because it is being returned and the function's return type is given as `T[]` in the `.d.ts`?  Currently it doesn't.  You could imagine enhancing the inference that way, but doing so might have other undesired effects and there will always be some more complicated scenario the inference can't handle.

Comment: Actually, I am not questioning the inferring ability of the compiler, and what I am asking is if it is true in *.d.ts file, the TypeScript compiler could omit a certain information to pass the validation at compile.

Comment: Fair enough, we're not talking about the inference algorithm used by normal compilation as such, but trying to reconstruct from the .d.ts a set of function body annotations that will pass the compiler is essentially the same problem, and a hard one in general.  (It's also an ill-defined one: if you allow type assertions, then any code can trivially pass, while if you don't allow them, much real-world code will be unable to pass.)

Comment: I think I follow your point. You probably stick to my word usage "the type-safety", and insist it's not type-safe, am I correct.  To be precise I wrote and meant " the type-safety of the vanilla JS code" to a certain extent that it actually has passed the compiler validation, and if it's possible to restore the validation process using the *.d.ts output, that is essentially used in the validation process.

Comment: I don't see the distinction you are trying to make.  TypeScript has no "validation process" other than checking code against its definition of "type safety".

Comment: The point is when there is a process `A->B+C` or , `A== B+C`and now you have information B&C in the separate components in your hand, is it possible to reconstruct the `B+C` in the same component. I have an impression you insist "no because B+C has less information than A", and now I doubt 1. in fact, your answer does not correspond to my question in the first place, 2. is it really true that  B+C has less information than A"

Comment: Sure, given the `.d.ts` and `.js`, I see no fundamental obstacle to constructing a `.ts` that contains the information of both of them.  What that `.ts` would lack compared to the original is the function body annotations, which are needed to check type safety and hard to automatically reconstruct in complex cases (I believe the problem can be proved undecidable under appropriate assumptions).  Your question mentioned "validity" several times; if you meant something by that, I still don't see what it could be other than type safety.

Comment: " What that .ts would lack compared to the original is the function body annotations, which are needed to check type safety and hard to automatically reconstruct in complex cases." Thanks, ok, but again, I am so inexperienced in TypeScript, and never seen such a case, and that's why I simply thought it's reconstructable. Here, I mean by reconstructable,if the source, A is passed with no error, then the reconstructed B+C also had the same type-safe level of the A. and the sample code you kindly have provided here, unfortunately, did not convince me for the difference.

Comment: I have investigated further with my code with complicated 3 level curried and recursuive function. `.d.ts` failed to type as a recursive return, which is lame, but the type check safety level is the same between the original .ts and .d.ts, no information loss, and I add an interface to clarify with the recursive structure for the function and clarify the return value as the interface. The .d.ts obviously includes the interface code, hence this also no information loss. I must say I have to disagree to your answer so far.